# preset and reset mat-datepicker in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

In my Angular 5 app I use the DatePicker from the Material Design (mat-datepicker). The default behavior of the datepicker works, but I have no way to preset a date and reset it in the associated input element.  Could anyone help?   Thanks. The datepicker resides in another containing component (snippet 1).

**Snippet 1 (containing page):**

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <matDatepicker [initDate]="newVisitDate" (newDatePickedEvent)="setNewVisitDate($event)"></matDatepicker>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <input [ngModel]="newVisitDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'" (ngModelChange)="setNewVisitDate($event)" class="form-control" type="date" name="newVisitDate" id="newVisitDate" #newVisitDateVar="ngModel" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**Snippet 2 (mat-datepicker.html):**

```html
<div class="datepicker-container">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input disabled matInput [matDatepicker]="pickedDate" (dateChange)="newDatePicked($event)" placeholder="New Visit Date" id="matSelectedDate">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="pickedDate"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker disabled="false" #pickedDate [startAt]="someDate"></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

**Snippet 3 (mat-datepicker.ts):**

```js
import {
  Component,
  Output,
  EventEmitter,
  Input,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  MatDatepickerInputEvent
} from '@angular/material';

/** @title Basic datepicker */
@Component({
  selector: 'matDatepicker',
  templateUrl: 'mat-datepicker.html',
  styleUrls: ['mat-datepicker.css']
})
export class matDatepickerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() initDate: Date;
  @Output() newDatePickedEvent: EventEmitter <Date> = new EventEmitter();
  someDate: Date;

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.initDate === undefined) {
      this.someDate = new Date();
      console.log('matDatepicker.ngOnInit.initDate(using new Date())=', this.someDate);
    } else {
      this.someDate = this.initDate;
      console.log('matDatepicker.ngOnInit.initDate(using @input)=', this.someDate);
    }
  }

  newDatePicked(event: MatDatepickerInputEvent <Date> ): void {
    console.log('emitting matDatepickerCompont.newDatePicked()', event.value);
    this.newDatePickedEvent.emit(event.value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To preset a date, you can do something like:

**datepicker-value-example.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="Angular forms" [formControl]="date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

**datepicker-value-example.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-value-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-value-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-value-example.css'],
})
export class DatepickerValueExample {
  date = new FormControl(new Date(100000000000));
}
```

[Working snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5v2hof)

EDIT: new [snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5v2hof) with custom format. If you want the actual material element to display the custom format you can have a look at `Datepicker with custom formats` in the [Angular Material Datepicker page](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples), even though when you open it in StackBlitz it doesn't seem to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I am getting an error:

SCRIPT5022: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'formConrol' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="pickedDate"
           [ERROR ->][formConrol]="someDate" placeholder="New Visit Date" id="matSelectedDate">
    <mat-datepicker-toggl"): ng:///AppModule/matDatepickerComponent.html@4:11
File: eval code (846), Line: 24889, Column: 13

Comment: I suspect that's a typo, you probably want `formControl` instead of `formConrol`

Comment: ah, thank you. it was a typo.  Could you please show me how I can make the formControl to show MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm.  I could only get it show date but no time.

Comment: Well, Javascript supports different `Date` formats, but the material component doesn't. If you think about it from a usability point of view, would you want to let a user pick a specific calendar day and also a specific hour, or would that be the hour when they select the option?

If you need more complex UI, you might want to consider using the `DatePicker` just for the day and another custom element for the hour.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I need to default the hour and minute to show Date.now, even users do not get to select the hour and the minute.

Comment: I've modified the above answer to consider the new format, see if that helps.

Comment: awesome.  It is possible to use <input ...[formControl]="formControlDate" [value]="formatDate"> so that the hour and time are shown in the matInput?

Comment: What about reset?